# Represent a number as a sum of a subset of an array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a natural number S>10, I would like to generate an array of N natural numbers A = (a1, a2, …, aK, …, aN) such that S is a sum of M ai.

Constraint 1:

```
ai < S/2
```

Constraint 2:

```
M >= K
```

Constraint 3 (optional): `ai != aj`

Sorry, I’m not sure how to describe this problem using proper mathematical notation, but the idea is simple: generate some values that would add up to a pre-defined total. And then add some more values (“decoys” as it were) to make the task of selecting the right values to use more difficult.

Let's say S=18 and I want it to be represented as a sum of at least 3 values. So, a "winning" array would be A=(7,8,3,4,5) because 7+8+3=18 and there's no way to use less than 3 values to get 18.

I already have a simple algorithm that kinda works:

```
Input: 
S - the sum
K - the number of values required to add up to S
N - the total number of values (includes the decoys)

Output: 
A - the array of values ai

1) Generate K values by dividing S by K and then adding and subtracting some random numbers. This ensures that ai will be more or less random while still adding up to S.

2) Generate (N-K) random values less than S/2 each.

3) Combine all the generated values into one array A.

4) Test that S can be represented as a sum of no less than K values from the array A. If not, discard A and return to 1)

Example:
S = 20
K = 3
N = 5
ai values generated: 7, 1, 12, 4, 8,
7+1+12=20 – This is what we need (3 values add up to 20)

But we also can get 20 with only 2 values and this violates Constraint 2:
12+8 = 20
```

Of course, this is a brute-force approach and I check for too many iterations, but it's obviously not the right way to do it.

My question: Is it possible to generate the array A so that it would automatically meet Constraint 1,2,3 or at least Constraints 1,2?

Comment: what does your brute force approach consist of?

Comment: @paulpaul1076: It's included in the question, starting with "Input: S - the sum".

Answer (score 0):

For positive integers, the short answer is no: counterexample
S=1 K=2. However, avoiding the obvious,

```
createLongList(S,K)
{
  list= {};
  for(i=1 to s/2)
    if(canAdd(list,S,K,i))
      list.add(i);
    else break;
}
```

Will this create a maximum size list? Maybe not, but it will do pretty well. Without getting into the math, a recursive search will give a guaranteed best result.

```
#list=={} the first time, istart=S/2
createLongList(S,list,K,istart)
{
  bestList=list;
  for(i=istart to 1)
     if(canAdd(list,S,K,i))
       newList=createLongList(S,list++i,K,i-1);
       if(newList.isLongerThan(bestList))
         bestList=newList;
  return bestList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the case of S=1. I updated the question to S>10. Could you elaborate on how the canAdd() function would work? Would it be testing all ai combinations? If so, I was thinking of that, but this seems like a variation on the brute-force approach that I already have in place.

Comment: canAdd is testing if element i can be added. For the purposes of this problem, if K==4, it searches for two other elements already in the list (a,b) such that a+b+i==S as if a+b+i==S, i cannot be legally added.

Comment: Don't forget that  canAdd(ai) should test all permutations of adding ai to the existing values. In your example we should test a+i, b+i, ...

Suppose N=6 and K=3. Then we have to call canAdd(a4), canAdd(a5) and canAdd(a6). In my existing algorithm (step 4) I'm only calling canAdd(a6) to achieve the same result. Perhaps I'm missing something in your solution?

I think the whole approach of randomly selecting ai values and testing them is not efficient. I suspect that there might be an algorithm that will automatically guarantee that the constraints are met.

Comment: My second solution as outlined is literally the exhaustive search. It may take a long time, but if you want guarantee, it is right there above this comment.

Comment: I was looking for a faster and a more intelligent way to generate that array. Both yours and my solutions are basically "let's try some values and see if they meet the constraints"